# App running in service mode can have user interface?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, android-bluetooth, android-service-binding

My application runs when bluetooth is on and even it should detect events from other devices if app is in backgroud mode. So i have to make my app in Service mode. Is it possible to have User interface if app is running in service mode.what are all the disadavantages if i run my app in service mode? like battery? memory?.
is there any better solution please guide me.

Comment: If you want GUI then why are you making service? Just make a broadcast receiver and make an Activity to notify when bluetooth activated.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Service Mode". A `Service` is just a component like any other component. You can have any combination of `Services`,  `Activities` or whatever you want in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I take that you are a beginner in android development
So I'll explain these things to you

### 1.App in background mode

First of all there is no such thing as 'Service Mode'. What you want to do is to create a background service that can run even if the application is not in foreground. And the whole app does not go as service only

### 2.Can I have user interface in service mode

From the first question you may now have an idea that it can use both foreground 
Actvities and background services(Research on Actvities and Services in android). Yes even if an app has a service it can also have UI components like activities,fragments,dialogs etc.

### 3.Disadvantages of running a background service

Nothing in particular and it depends on the operation that you are planning to do in the service (And yes less operations means less battery consumption and CPU usage)